# Flex: LinkButton select=true has no visible effect

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mxml

I would like to have a LinkButton programmatically selected.
So I have a code like this:
`<mx:LinkButton label="hello42" selected="{isHello42}"/>`

`isHello42` is true but the LinkButtons doesn't look like it's selected.
Do I have to change the complete skin to achieve that the LinkButton look like it's selected?

Here it look like setting selected=true should work: http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/09/06/creating-a-toggleable-linkbutton-control-in-flex/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read your mentioned article on blog.flexamples.com accurately! It's answering your question by itself. The desired behavior is achieved by extending the `mx.skins.halo.LinkButtonSkin`.

Comment: I should've mentioned that I'm using the spark theme, when using the `mx.skins.halo.LinkButtonSkin` there is no "background" on the LinkButton in default state. Neither changes the background at "MouseOver"...

Comment: I missed the wood for the trees, just extending this skin. I'm sorry :)